# SQL Server Data Mining resources

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, data-mining

I'm new to Data Mining but not that new to SQL Server. I'm looking for best resources to get me what I want as fast as possible. I want to know about SQL Server Data Mining. Is there any resource(s) you would recommend? I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at http://www.sqlserverdatamining.com/ssdm/, which is run by the SQL Server Data Mining product team at Microsoft and has tutorials, whitepapers, articles, tips and tricks, and downloads. Also, take a look at the book "Data Mining with Microsoft SQL Server 2008"; it was coauthored by members of the product team.

I also always recommend, if it's your first time out of the gate with the feature, that you go through the tutorials in Books Online. They give you a broad overview of the features involved in data mining and some initial hands-on experience. Certainly not enough to make you an expert, but enough to give you a basic idea of how data mining works.

Comment: Well after I posted this question here, I found out about that website. I'm pretty much pleased with these recommendations but I want to hold on to your answer and not setting it as an answer for a while to see if any other person would give me something better or at least as interesting as this one. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the book [Data Mining with SQL Server 2008](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470277742) - (Disclaimer - I wrote it with a colleague while I was the dev manager for SSAS, but it is the best SQL DM book!)

Also look at my blog (this is a good post digest - http://jamiemaclennan.blogspot.com/2010/03/dmx-posting-digest.html)